# editable and non-editable input fields switcher

Tags: php

With below example I now get always **editable input fields**. After the ajax update there is an fa-check icon displayed.
How can I **turn / switch** these input fields **into** **non-editable / editable** when I declare a var:

> $edit = "1" or "0"

Here the code:

```
<div class="form-field"><label>'. __('first_name', 'agent-plugin').':</label>
<input class="input_field" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="'. __('first_name', 'agent-plugin').'" data-pk="'.$uid.'" value="'.($uid ? $result->first_name: '' ).'" />
<i class="fa fa-check" style="display:none;"></i></div>
<div class="form-field"><label>'. __('last_name', 'agent-plugin').':</label>
<input class="input_field" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="'. __('last_name', 'agent-plugin').'" data-pk="'.$uid.'" value="'.($uid ? $result->last_name: '' ).'" />
<i class="fa fa-check" style="display:none;"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check variable $edit value. If is 0 you must put html attribute **readonly**

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp